# How to find products in one group but not the other

Tags: mysql, array-difference

I currently have this SQL query:

```
SELECT
    product.name "Product",
    section.floor "Floor"
FROM
    products
JOIN
    sales
ON
    products.productID = sales.productID
JOIN
    sections
ON
    sales.sectionID = sections.sectionID
WHERE
    sections.floor = 1 // BUT NOT ON FLOOR = 2
```

My idea is to see which products are sold on the first floor but NOT on the second floor. I manage to get all products sold on the first, but how can I get rid of the products that are also found on the second?

My thought is to get all products sold on both floors, and remove the list of products sold and remove those from the list of all products on the first floor, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Unless you're sure you know what you're doing, if you find yourself using a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions, the chances are that you're doing something wrong!

Comment: Oh, sorry, removed it, have no idea why I've typed that GROUP BY here, I'm aware of the aggregating functions, really sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have no need for your GROUP BY statement, so you can get rid of that.

If you want to avoid second floor objects, you should select all products from the first floor at first, and add another subquery that filters out products that are also sold on the second floor.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT p.name, s.floor
FROM products p
JOIN sales sa ON sa.productid = p.productid
JOIN sections s ON s.sectionid = sa.sectionid
WHERE s.floor = 1 
   AND p.productid NOT IN(
      SELECT p.productid
      FROM products p
      JOIN sales sa ON sa.productid = p.productid
      JOIN sections s ON s.sectionid = sa.sectionid
      WHERE s.floor = 2)
```

Another way to think about the above is this: Give me every product name and floor for all products sold on the first floor where that productid is not one of the productids that is sold on the second floor.

Comment: Re reading your question, I'm not entirely sure if you want products on floor 1 or 2, but the concept remains the same.

Comment: Yes, you got it right, I was looking for products sold on floor 1 but not on floor 2. I was thinking i can simply pull that out with one two joins and not making another sub query :D but, seems like I can't.

Comment: No, I don't think so. When you think about it like I said "get items in one position but not the other" that just screams subquery in my head.